# Custom Integral Loss Term Keras

Tags: python, optimization, neural-network, keras

I am trying to define a custom loss function in Keras where I have an additional term that is an integral over the domain of the neural network output. So this would look like:

[image: integral]

The key point is that the integral runs over an entire domain that I've specified, not just training data. I don't mind using any form of quadrature to evaluate the integral, I just need to be able to evaluate it. Currently, as far as the documentation indicates, this is not possible to do with a custom loss as it only provides access to `y_pred` and `y_true`.

Is there any way of achieving this in Keras?

Comment: Could you add more details on how your model is defined (especially output)?

Comment: i have the same problem, do you have any solution yet? I know we can do this through scipy.integral. but i dont know if there any existing api we can use with keras

Answer (score -1):

If the idea is just defining extra variables, you can do this either inside (locally) or outside (globally) the loss function, using keras backend functions:

```
import keras.backend as K

myDomain = K.variable(range(100)) / 10 #for instance  

def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    localVar = K.variable([[1,2],[3,1]])

    return calculationsWith(y_true,y_pred,localVar,myDomain)
```

It's important that you use functions coming from the backend to do the calculations. (Either from `K` or directly from tensoflow, theano or CNTK).

Comment: Not quite. The idea is I need to evaluate the network itself at points independent of my data. I guess part of my question would be if it is allowed to evaluate the network within a loss function? I imagine it may complicate things since networks are stateful, but I could be wrong. Also if I do that, will Keras still manage the automatic differentiation.

Comment: As long as you keep using backend functions and don't abandon the `y_pred` values, it will be differentiable. This evaluation, though, might have to be done between training batches, evaluate first, store the values, then fit the batch. The evaluation itself will be considered constant values regarding differentiation.